# Do the Templates in django need to move to public while using Passenger

Tags: python, django, passenger

Very familiar with python and Flask, but just getting started with Django.

**ENVIRONMENT**

Dreamhost, Django 1.9 (i think), python 2.7.3, Passenger

**PROBLEM STMT**

I have my app working and can generate an index page using HttpResponse straight from views.py.  However, when I try to incorporate templates, I am getting "TemplateDoesNotExist at /"

Because I'm new, I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting.  Is this a passenger issue or Django?

**DETAILS**

I've modified my [DIRS] in settings.py to reference the templates directory.

```
'DIRS': ['CTracker/templates'],
```

I then created the templates directory under CTracker and the 'clientadmin' (the name of my app) directory and finally the index.html file.

```
-CTracker
 |
 |-CTracker
 | |
 | -templates
 |  |
 |  -clientadmin
 |   |
 |    -index.html
 |-manage.py
```

My function in views.py uses the following return.

```
return render(request, 'clientadmin/index.html', {
        'clients': client,
    })
```

**Troubleshooting Done**

- Double checked the files exist and the path to the file appears
  correct in both the filesystem and the settings.py file.
- I tried running 'manage.py collectstatics' but 0 files were moved.

Thank you in advance.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should look at the **full** error message that Django shows you. It should tell you the directories that the template loader searched. This often lets you figure out what's wrong with your settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items in the `DIRS` list should be the full path, for example:

```
'DIRS': ['/path/to/CTracker/CTracker/templates'],
```

The Django settings file should have a `BASE_DIR` defined. You can use this with `os.path.join` to avoid hardcoding the full path.

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'CTracker', 'templates')]
```

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks that worked.   Used:  

  'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'CTracker/templates')],